# Xamarin.Forms Font Family not working on Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, label, effects

I have problem with both things. I want to new font but it not working at all. I added .ttf to Assets and i Have changed build Action to AndroidAsset

My Xaml code

```
<Label Text="My Challenges" TextColor="#000000" BackgroundColor="#80FFFFFF" FontSize="20" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" x:Name="Lab">
  <Label.FontFamily>
   <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">                
    <OnPlatform.Android>BLOODSUC.TTF#BLOODSUC</OnPlatform.Android>
</OnPlatform>
</Label.FontFamily>

<Label.Effects>
   <local:ShadowEffects Radius="10" DistanceX="5" DistanceY="5">
      <local:ShadowEffects.Color>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
           <On Platform="iOS" Value="Black" />
             <On Platform="Android" Value="#c4babb" />
               <On Platform="UWP" Value="Red" />
         </OnPlatform>
       </local:ShadowEffects.Color>
    </local:ShadowEffects>
  </Label.Effects>
</Label>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct name ? (the part after the #) You can double check by opening the .ttf file in windows. The popup will display the font name

Comment: yes i'm sure. I have checked

Comment: Seems the problem is with your font file, I downloaded one, have the same problem as you. In the meanwhile I tested other fonts here: https://fonts.google.com/?selection.family, works fine.

Comment: Ok, thanks for help